# Microsoft Sidewinder Strategic Commander (USB Device) - Any open source drivers or tools?

Tags: usb

I have an old USB gaming device called the Strategic Commander.  It was handy for strategy games like Age of Empires - allowing for easy left hand to control of scrolling, panning, zooming and using a variety of programmable hotkeys.  Today it's a useless/unsupported/forgotten item that sits in a drawer in my office.  I would like to use the device to help navigate in a 3D CAD environment like Blender or 3D Studio Max.  On Windows 7 & 8.

Is there any existing research/work available in this area?

Is there an open source driver framework?

Does anyone know Microsoft's official stance on 'hacking' this old hardware?

How should I get started?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There's a post at http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-hardware/need-windows-7-drivers-for-sidewinder-strategic/27cabb00-b9b6-425b-8593-87f2ef7663f6 about it:

> I find it was VERY hard to download the driver directly from
> http://strategic-engine.software.informer.com/1.3/ so I am sharing
> another link.
>
> I did successfully install the drivers from this website
> http://www.picturemon.com/Downloads/StrategicSetupv1.3.zip
>
> the web
> owner stated on
> http://www.vistaheads.com/forums/microsoft-public-windows-vista-hardware-devices/10329-sidewinder-strategic-commander-problems-11.html
>
> "Okay, I Finally found a copy thanks guys (sarcasm) so others can
> download it. I'm putting it on my website. Oh and if the author of you
> software wants me too take it down don't hesitate to shoot me an email
> thanks."
>
> This version does work on my Win 7 64 Bit computer.
>
> I also posted it
> on my personal site so more people can use it.
>
> [http://home.comcast.net/~formosanh/Sidewinder/StrategicSetupv1.3.zip](http://home.comcast.net/%7Eformosanh/Sidewinder/StrategicSetupv1.3.zip)

Except for the first link ("VERY hard to download"), the others all seem down.

Google found http://pds27.egloos.com/pds/201501/28/48/StrategicSetupv1.3.zip, but given the suspicious origin and current file host, I'd recommend you take proper precautions before installing it (lest it contain malicious functionality).

[image: Strategic Engine]